# choose the right doublette to delete

Tags: spss

I have a dataset with 400.000 cases. The problem is, there are sometimes around 21.000 doublettes for one case. Another problem is that I can't just delete the doublettes, cause I don't know which case is complete with all information. Unfortunately there is no date of modification. So I'd like to know if there's any possibility to choose the case with the most information to delete all the doublettes with less information.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest counting the missing/empty cells in each row and then selecting the rows with the minimum number of empty cells - for each ID.

```
*First creating some fake data for demonstration. 
*I'm constructing this so it contains a mixture of string and number variables.

DATA LIST list/ID (f) Svar1 (a1) Nvar1(f) Svar2 (a1) Nvar2(f).
begin data
111,'a',1,'a',2
111,p ,1,'b', 
111,'c',1, ,1
222,'v',1, ,2
222,'k',2,'x',2
222,'n',,'z',
end data.

* note the separate treatment of string and number variables.

count EmptyCells=Svar1 Svar2("") Nvar1 Nvar2 (sysmis).
aggregate /outfile=* mode=addvariables   /break=id   /EmptyCells_min=min(EmptyCells).

* variable EmptyCells now contains the count of empty cells in every row.
* EmptyCells_min has the minimum number of empty cells in a row for every ID.

select if EmptyCells_min=EmptyCells.
```

After selecting, you are left with the row that has the maximum number of non-empty cells for each ID. 
Note - you may be left with a number of rows for one ID - all containing the same number of non empty cells. You'll have to decide how to select among those rows, or to think about aggregating them.